# real-time resizing in Parallax Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I was using the **stellar.js** in my project. 
There is a question - under the **"realtime resize"** requirement( **do not reload page** ).
when I using the **resize function** to calculate the new position **LEFT** in horizontal scrolling below:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var newPos = element.position().left*100; //Get NEW Position ...
    element.css("left", newPos);        //It's not working ...
});
```

the elements with **"data-stellar-ratio"** will not be overwrite.
How do i do to slove this problem ? 
Thanks for your help.

**Under the requirement below**
-> When resizing browser then recalculate the element position **in real-time ( NO Reload page )** 
-> So, I will recalculate position and overwrite new position to element. 
-> But, the element which use data-stellar-ratio attribute **can not be overwrite new position**.(example in comment)
here is my problem. thank you for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. But, if you wish to change the data-stellar-ratio attribute, you would do it like this.

```
element.attr('data-stellar-ratio', 2);
```

`element` must be a jQuery object.

Comment: in normally, If window innerWidth is **1000px** when I setting the **LEFT position 50%** then we get the LEFT position **500px** in element, now we **resize the window to 500px**, we should get the left position is **250px**, but I still get 500px in the element position and I can't **overwrite** the position in element when the page **no reload**

Answer (score 0):

To you refer 
_repositionElements: function() in stellar.js

```
if (this.options.horizontalScrolling) {
 var bSize = this.options.refWidth,bResize = $(window).width(),bRatio = this.options.formula(bResize, bSize);

newPositionLeft = (scrollLeft + particle.horizontalOffset + this.viewportOffsetLeft + particle.startingPositionLeft - particle.startingOffsetLeft + particle.parentOffsetLeft) * -(particle.stellarRatio + fixedRatioOffset - 1) + particle.startingPositionLeft; 

newPositionLeft *= bRatio;   //all element reposition in here

newOffsetLeft = newPositionLeft - particle.startingPositionLeft + particle.startingOffsetLeft;

}
```

bSize = resizing browser before 
bResize = resizing browser after 
bRatio = resize ratio 
**newPositionLfet** = all element position left 
**newPositionTop** = the same to **newPositionLeft**